# Library to load images into textures, Linux, C and OpenGl

Tags: opengl, textures, c, loading, linux

I am looking for simple, self-contained C library for Linux to load images from files into OpenGL textures. The licence should be quite liberal: zlib, bsd, mit or something. I have found [SOIL](http://www.lonesock.net/soil.html), however it hasn't been updated for a long time. Is there something else, or do I have to write my own?

P.S.
I use glfw. There are only deprecated functions for loading images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use [STB Image](https://github.com/nothings/stb) for most image loading. A small self contained no strings attached implementation of png and other file formats.

Comment: SOIL is a light wrapper around stb_image.

Comment: Ah, I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 11):

[SOIL](http://www.lonesock.net/soil.html) works great. Who cares if it hasn't been updated in a "long time"? That just means it's stable and well-understood.

(It actually was updated in 2008, which is not long ago at all.)

Comment: For those seeing this now - SOIL doesn't seem to work on iOS, so if portability is your aim, using stb_image directly may be a better option.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/). It's dual-licensed, you may choose either GPL or the liberal FreeImage license. It supports far more image formats than SOIL and development is active.

The library itself is written in C++, but it has an ANSI C interface.

From its introduction:

> Thanks to it's ANSI C interface, FreeImage is usable in many languages including C, C++, VB, C#, Delphi, Java and also in common scripting languages such as Perl, Python, PHP, TCL or Ruby.

Comment: It looks the licence is not liberal enough.

Comment: @Michas All it requires you is to acknowledge the use of the library, otherwise you are free to modify the sources and use in commercial projects. Or maybe I did not read the license carefully enough?

Comment: I may be forced to publish some of source code.

Comment: I'm not sure where you are getting that idea... are you actually going to modify the FreeImage library (hint: probably not; be honest with yourself)?

Comment: It is not a practical requirement. I know. I just would be happier with more liberal licence.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [DevIL](http://openil.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: DevIL is under LGPL. This is little too restrictive for me.

Comment: Keep in mind that as long as you don't modify the original source code, you can link to a LGPL library and keep your main code closed/private/used for commercial purposes.

Comment: I know. However I want to link everything into single file.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to read many formats, consider writing your own loader code. I use libjpeg and libpng directly and they're quite easy to use. Both have very simple functions that essentially fetch a scanline of RGBA data, just put that into an array and then upload to OpenGL. Both have very useful and straightforward example programs.

I have no experience with other formats, though. But to be honest, PNG+JPEG cover 100% of our needs (which aren't trivial nor hobbyist level - see http://www.mysterystudio.com)

Comment: Actually I found your answer pretty useful as PNG and JPEG do cover most of my needs. Not sure why you did not get more upvotes since the libraries you mention also have a permissive license.

Answer (score 0):

[Silly](http://www.cegui.org.uk/wiki/index.php/SILLY_Downloads_0.1.0) is produced the the [CEGUI](http://www.cegui.org.uk/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) guys.

I supports loading PNG, TGA, JPG, etc.  And it's released with an MIT license.

You'd have to write a C wrapper yourself as the library is written in C++.

Comment: The problem is I want to compile everything with a C compiler.